# Kubernetes canary deployment routing based on geographic location

Tags: kubernetes

I have built a simple canary deployment in Kubernetes GCP but I dont have any control of the traffic routing , right now its random.

Ideally I would like to control the routing based on the Geographic location , however browser-agent would also do or any parameter where i can control the routing.

I followed the canary deployment technique using this [link](https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/k8s-deployment-strategies)

Is there something in-built provided by k8s ?

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Canary Deployments using Istio](https://istio.io/blog/canary-deployments-using-istio.html).

For example, the following rule will only apply to an incoming request if it includes a “cookie” header that contains the substring “user=jason”.

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: ratings-jason
spec:
  destination:
    name: reviews
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        cookie:
          regex: "^(.*?;)?(user=jason)(;.*)?$"
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards Istio.

I was able to do the sample bookinfo with istio  but my own app was throwing some issues.

But yeah , Istio is the way !! Thanks.